# How do I start my WifiDirect activity from my home screen?

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

I have two buttons on my start screen, one for starting google maps. And one "search button" for wanting to find peers and connect to them via WiFi direct. When I press the search button I want the app to start searching directly, and displaying the peers. What should I write for the "WiFiDirectActivity" to start when I press the search button on my HomeScreen?

My HomeScreen class:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

    Button mapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);

    mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    Button sensorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sensorBtn);

    sensorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, WiFiDirectActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

}
```

My WiFiDirectActivity class:

```
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener, DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener {

public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";
private WifiP2pManager manager;
private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
private boolean retryChannel = false;

private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

/**
 * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
 */
public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_peers);

    // add necessary intent values to be matched.

    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);


    Button sensorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sensorBtn);

    sensorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
            manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }

    });

}

/** register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent values to be matched */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

/**
 * Remove all peers and clear all fields. This is called on
 * BroadcastReceiver receiving a state change event.
 */
public void resetData() {
    DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
    DeviceDetailFragment fragmentDetails = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    if (fragmentList != null) {
        fragmentList.clearPeers();
    }
    if (fragmentDetails != null) {
        fragmentDetails.resetViews();
    }
}

@Override
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.showDetails(device);

}

@Override
public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {
    manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void disconnect() {
    final DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.resetViews();
    manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onChannelDisconnected() {
    // we will try once more
    if (manager != null && !retryChannel) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        resetData();
        retryChannel = true;
        manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Severe! Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void cancelDisconnect() {

    /*
     * A cancel abort request by user. Disconnect i.e. removeGroup if
     * already connected. Else, request WifiP2pManager to abort the ongoing
     * request
     */
    if (manager != null) {
        final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        if (fragment.getDevice() == null
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED) {
            disconnect();
        } else if (fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.INVITED) {

            manager.cancelConnect(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Aborting connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this,
                            "Connect abort request failed. Reason Code: " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
}
```

The code that I am trying to redo from a search button in the menu to a search button on a different screen. (I removed the direct discover).

```
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener, DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener {

...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_items, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.atn_direct_enable:
            if (manager != null && channel != null) {

                // Since this is the system wireless settings activity, it's
                // not going to send us a result. We will be notified by
                // WiFiDeviceBroadcastReceiver instead.

                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "channel or manager is null");
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.atn_direct_discover:
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + isWifiP2pEnabled);

            if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
            manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start to perform search in onResume as follows :

```
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener, DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener {

public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";
private WifiP2pManager manager;
private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
private boolean retryChannel = false;

private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

/**
 * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
 */
public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_peers);

    // add necessary intent values to be matched.

    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);


    Button sensorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sensorBtn);

    sensorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
            manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }

    });

}

/** register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent values to be matched */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    performSearch(); // start searching devices
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

/**
 * Remove all peers and clear all fields. This is called on
 * BroadcastReceiver receiving a state change event.
 */
public void resetData() {
    DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
    DeviceDetailFragment fragmentDetails = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    if (fragmentList != null) {
        fragmentList.clearPeers();
    }
    if (fragmentDetails != null) {
        fragmentDetails.resetViews();
    }
}

@Override
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.showDetails(device);

}

@Override
public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {
    manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void disconnect() {
    final DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.resetViews();
    manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onChannelDisconnected() {
    // we will try once more
    if (manager != null && !retryChannel) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        resetData();
        retryChannel = true;
        manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Severe! Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void cancelDisconnect() {

    /*
     * A cancel abort request by user. Disconnect i.e. removeGroup if
     * already connected. Else, request WifiP2pManager to abort the ongoing
     * request
     */
    if (manager != null) {
        final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        if (fragment.getDevice() == null
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED) {
            disconnect();
        } else if (fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.INVITED) {

            manager.cancelConnect(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Aborting connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this,
                            "Connect abort request failed. Reason Code: " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}

private void performSearch() {
   if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
        manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now when I have WifiP2p enabled, I still get that "isWifiP2pEnabled" == false.

Comment: setIsWifiP2pEnabled() is not being called anywhere, thus isWifiP2pEnabled variable will always remain false.

Comment: But it is called in my WifiBroadcastReceiver class? Shouldn't that be called when I create my "receiver" in OnResume()?

Comment: Yes, it will be called but that code is present in your `WifiBroadcastReceiver` class. So, either you will have to implement your broadcast receiver code in `WifiDirectActivity` or create a preference for managing whether wifi direct is enabled or not.

Comment: But why does it work in this case then? (I edited code). I want to remove the menu and instead have the search button on a separate screen. But "isWifiP2pEnabled" returns true in the above code.